# How to add data from one table into a 2nd table but only in a row that is a match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One Table is called "Location" and a 2nd table is called "items" they look like this.

```
        Location                           Items
----------------------------------------------------------
Bin_Number  | Contains |||  Item_Number    | Location
----------------------------------------------------------
A1          |          |||  12345          | A2
A2          |          |||  12346          | A4
A3          |          |||  12347          | A3
A4          |          |||
```

How would I write a query that would display all bins and also have the item number next to the bin if it contains one?

I would like an output like this.

```
        Location         
-----------------------
Bin_Number  | Contains 
-----------------------
A1          |          
A2          | 12345         
A3          | 12347         
A4          | 12346
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Thanks for that, I just updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join`

```
select bin_number,item_number as contains
   from location left join items on location = bin_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and how the columns appear to be presented, I gather that this may be the query that might be usable to start off with.

Assumptions:

- Location table contains a single column named 'Bin_Number'

  Items table contains two columns: 'Item_Number' and 'Location'

```
select
   t1.bin_number,
   t2.item_number
   from location t1
   join items t2
   on t2.location = t1.bin_number
   where t2.item_number is not null
```

Comment: ok that works but the issue i have is that now A1 will not show up

Comment: try it now, there was a type

Comment: yeah i just caught it and fixed it but A1 will not show up.

Comment: Then you would stub out the `where` clause entirely. The question you asked was to `... write a query that would display all bins and also have the item number next to the bin if it contains one?` If the item number does't have a bin, shouldn't it be filtered out?